# Any approximation or solution for integral of Macdonald Function multiplying by Exponential Function multiplying by Linear Function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, approximation, bessel-functions

Is there any approximate solution for this integral, $$\int_0^\infty v^{m-1} K_0\bigg(2 \sqrt{\frac{v}{yz}}\bigg) \exp\bigg[-\frac{a v}{b}\bigg]\,\Bbb dv.$$

Please provide some reference with the answers if possible. Below are some reference books which have similar integrals but I couldn’t find anything:

[[1]](https://books.google.com.pk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&oi=fnd&pg=PR3&dq=Table%20of%20Integrals,%20Series,%20and%20Products%20Seventh%20Edition&ots=bMluVZG8LD&sig=47_6IqhAADK6hDZv_zJWSPiELBk)

[[2]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c43b/1e69a5c326fc33dc30e8042f86884a3e5192.pdf)

Comment: Need to know what $a(v)$ is...

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the question is updated now. Please refer to the equation.

Comment: What is $\circ$?

Comment: Your integral can be written $$\frac{{(yz)^{m - 1/2} }}{{4^{m - 1} }}\int_0^\infty  {t^{2m - 2} K_ \circ  (t)\exp \left( { - \alpha t^2 } \right)dt},$$ with $\alpha : = ayz/(4b)$. Does this help?

Comment: @Gary $K_\circ(.)$ is the Macdonald function (Modified Bessel function)

Comment: @Ali Raza I know, but what do you mean by Modified Bessel function of order "circle"?

Comment: @Gary $\circ$ is basically 0, means $\circ=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $a/b > 0$, $yz > 0$ and $m > 1/2$. By a simple change of integration variables and **6.631/3.** from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products* (seventh edition), we have
$$
\int_0^\infty  {v^{m - 1} K_0 \!\left( {2\sqrt {\frac{v}{{yz}}} } \right)\exp \left( { - \frac{{av}}{b}} \right)\mathrm{d}v}  = \frac{{(yz)^{m - 1/2} }}{{4^{m - 1} }}\int_0^\infty  {t^{2m - 2} K_0 (t)\exp ( - \alpha t^2 )\mathrm{d}t} \\ = \left( {\frac{{yz}}{4}} \right)^{m - 1/2} \alpha ^{1 - m} \Gamma ^2\! \left( {m - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\exp \left( {\frac{1}{{8\alpha }}} \right)W_{1 - m,0} \!\left( {\frac{1}{{4\alpha }}} \right),
$$
where $\alpha  = ayz/(4b)$ and $W$ is the Whittaker function.

Comment: Thanks @Gray appreciate it